# Return Url Redirection issues on Paypal

Tags: paypal, orchardcms, paypal-sandbox

I'm integrating my Orchard website with Paypal. I was successful in doing that as i'm able to proceed with sandbox account credentials and complete the payment and return to my website. But all of a sudden, when i'm trying to return to my website with the Return url that i have specified under Merchant account(Unchanged from the beginning), Thank you page of Paypal is reloading endlessly without throwing any error and neither returning back to my website. I haven't changed any settings.
I can also see click here anchor tag on Thank you page,specifying tx(transaction number) and other parameters. Can i know the reason why this is happening all of a sudden.

Comment: There is strictly no way anyone can answer this. You're not saying what module you're using, or giving any information whatsoever that could help figure out what went wrong.

Comment: I have created a custom module on Orchard by name "Cart" and i'm sending my cart information to Paypal with cmd="_xclick",i'm doing this process via sandbox test account. I'm landing into Thank you page after all the payment process. At the thank you page ,i should be redirected back to my website( since i have turned on my Redirect Return and specified my return url). My thank you page on sandbox is loading endlessly without making a call back to my website.Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Did you try to research or contact PayPal's support?